Error :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin and Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21 after changing Android studio from Iguana to LadyBug
Please help. I changed Android studio from Iguana to LadyBug and the project does not compile. There are two errors during compilation :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' and Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
      > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

I reinstalled the JVM and JDK. Like all implementations, I added them in current versions.
Here is my gradle file:
...
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ollo.stopsindicator"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.ollo.stopsindicator"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 28
        versionName = "1.28"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.15"

    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.09.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.27.0")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
}

I have no idea why the JVM Target is 21, I haven't set anything like that anywhere.
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:459)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:376)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.PropertyEvaluationException: Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.InputParameterUtils.prepareInputParameterValue(InputParameterUtils.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.lambda$visitRegularInputs$1(TaskExecution.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitRegularInputs(TaskExecution.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter.fingerprintInputProperties(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateWithOutputs(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionState$0(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:289)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:459)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:376)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:284)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.lambda$beforeRead$0(AbstractProperty.java:276)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueState.finalizeOnReadIfNeeded(ValueState.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:276)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:268)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:162)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.getOrNull(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ProviderResolutionStrategy$1.resolve(ProviderResolutionStrategy.java:27)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.DeferredUtil.unpack(DeferredUtil.java:59)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.DeferredUtil.unpackOrNull(DeferredUtil.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.InputParameterUtils.prepareInputParameterValue(InputParameterUtils.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.InputParameterUtils.prepareInputParameterValue(InputParameterUtils.java:30)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget$Companion.fromTarget(JvmTarget.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain$wireJvmTargetToToolchain$1$1.invoke(DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain$wireJvmTargetToToolchain$1$1.invoke(DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain$sam$org_gradle_api_Transformer$0.transform(DefaultKotlinJavaToolchain.kt)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueSupplier$Present.transform(ValueSupplier.java:518)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.mapValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:168)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:162)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:281)
    ... 80 more


What Java/JDK version do you use for running Gradle? Older Android Studio versions respectively the Gradle versions require JDK 11 or even JDK 8. If 21 would be the JDK version then this is too new.

Thank you very much for the quick tip. I'll start checking right now, I just don't know if there might be another JDK used by the Android Studio IDE or if it's the same JDK that's installed on windows....?

I have used all below solution but nothing worked, How you solve this?

Set below JDK settings in android studio
Download: Version 17 with JetBrain Runtime 17
For Solution check below images:

In first screenshot, you can see "Download JDK.." from there you can download  

Also need to set into build.gradle
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = "17"
}


You can just add kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "17" } to build.gradle. It is not necessary to manually select the JDK version in Android Studio.

Hello, There is no Gradle JDK section to choose from on my Android Studio? what should I do, I have MacBook as well.

hi @ArmaganGOK please open Android module in Android studio in case working with Flutter Project and this will show Gradle JDK Selection option on MacBook

I just upgraded to AS Ladybug patch 2. This Settings dialog does not appear to offer a Gradle JDK dropdown, it has been cut off from the 'Gradel Projects' subtitle. Any ideas what to do? I've tried some of the offers below to no progress.

This helped me. Thanks. :-)

I had the same problem, just change the JDK in Settings -> build, execution, deployment -> build tools -> gradle.
With the new android studio it updated the JDK to 21, even though the Java targeting version was 17.

Update to what value? I tried all the available, nothing helped

I changed it to 17, but the version you need might be different, look in module gradle file for source/target compatibility. If you don't have specified the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility try and declare them with the same version as the JVM.

I have tried your solution but not working. still same error -Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21 @DanielTurcan

Select: Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.
Then in list "Gradle JDK" select "corretto-17 Amazon Corretto 17.0.13"

In build.gradle under app folder, add this inside the android closure:
android {
    // .. other properties 
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    // .. other properties 
}


I added this and it worked for me.

Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21
It is not a bug. Kotlin still not support JDK 21
check it here
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/26589
Kotlin does not officially support JDK 21. Kotlin's JVM target versions typically trail behind the latest JDK releases to ensure stability, tooling support, and compatibility.
Kotlin JVM Target Compatibility
Current Kotlin Support: As of Kotlin 1.8 and 1.9, the maximum officially supported jvmTarget is 17. Kotlin releases aim to add support for newer JVM targets, but it usually lags behind official JDK releases.
Supported JVM Targets:
"1.8" - Target for Java 8 compatibility.
"11" - Target for Java 11 compatibility.
"17" - Target for Java 17 compatibility.
Date: 08-10-2024

so how to fix it? when you install the latest android studio it somehow updates to 21. which is obviously not supported.

The solution for me was to downgrade Android Studio back to the Koala version

You should upgrade Kotlin and Gradle to latest instead

in Flutter I added this fix to android/app/build.gradle
android {
   kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "19"
    }
}


I think this is caused by the incompatibility of kapt and the lower version of JDK. I have encountered the same problem in my project. I can solve the problem through any of the following methods, and personally recommend the second one

Reduce the version of JDK. (Go to File - Settings - Build,Execution,Deployment - Build Tools - Gradle. Then select a lower version of Gradle JDK such as 17 to Download and use.)

Migrate kapt to ksp, then upgrade kotlin and ksp versions from 1.8.22 to 2.0.20, and then it works.(I don't know if kapt is still available, it's just that ksp is the better option for me right now.)


In your gradle file, the kapt does not appear to be in use, maybe you can try to remove the kapt in your project.


I went to Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.
Under Gradle JDK, I found that JetBrains Runtime (JDK 21) was selected by default.
I changed this to Homebrew OpenJDK 17 (or any compatible JDK 17 installation) from the dropdown.
My Android Studio, Gradle plugin everything is up to date and latest.

I hope my experiences will help someone. The most important thing is to fill in carefully to the exact selection of configuration in the build.gradle.kts(app) file.
I made the following changes to run the project I wrote in Android Studio Iguana. It didn't work on Android Studio Lady Bug. I installed Android Studio Koala Feature Drop and then made changes to the configuration.
The most important thing for everything to work was to select Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.2"
    }

And once again, big thanks to Robert, who gave me the hint to check the configuration.

I reinstalled Iguana and magically it started working correctly without any trouble to me.

In my case, upgrading org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 to ver 1.9.20 solve this problem.

in flutter ,
copy app/build.gradle
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

past to the Flutter Plugins/[packageName]/android/app/build.gradle

If you don't want to lower JDK version
In every gradle module, where kapt is used, add this to build.gradle:
for build.gradle.kts (Kotlinscript):
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinJvmCompile> {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_17)
    }
}

for build.gradle (groovy):
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinJvmCompile) {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget = org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_17
    }
}

Pay attention to version – in my case it is JVM_17, but your setup may require another version, you can choose one here. But in most cases, 17 should be fine.
In this case, you won't have to change your JDK version (which is shipped with Android Studio), this hack will just restrict JVM target to lower version for tasks which can't handle JDK 21 – kapt tasks in this case.

The answer for me was to explicitly declare the kotlin version in my project build.gradle, as indicated in https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt
i.e.
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.21"
I picked 2.0.21 as the latest non-draft release and everything is now working as expected, with the Android Studio compiler.xml pointed at 21.
I am maintaining a legacy project which uses kapt, and I am not encountering any issues now that I have made that change.
